# Как добавить сразу нескольо строк в БД sqlite Python

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Как сделать что бы из списка в колонку 'title' можно было добавить сразу несколько строк с записями из списка (в каждой строке по одному элементу списка) ? Первый раз работаю с БД на Python.

```
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
c = conn.cursor()

title = ['Вова', 'Дима', 'Илья']

c.executemany("INSERT INTO Article(title) VALUES (?)",  (title))

conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

таблица Article столбец title

Comment: Вроде как это должно работать, единственное  `title = ['Вова', 'Дима', 'Илья']` => `title = [['Вова'], ['Дима'], ['Илья']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю получилось ли у вас исполнить свой код после моего комментария, но решил дополнить свой ответ и оформить в виде решения.

Ваш отрывок кода открывает уже готовую базу данных. После этого вы пытаетесь вы полнить запрос к БД с помощью метода `executemany()`. Но проблема в следующем. executemany проходит по вашему списку, берет первый элемент и пытается распаковать его (`values (?)`), а для этого этот элемент должен быть списком, кортежем или словарем. Здесь же у вас обычные строки. отсюда первое исправление `title = ['Вова', 'Дима', 'Илья']` => `title = [['Вова'], ['Дима'], ['Илья']]`

После этого код работает, при наличии созданной базы данных, с таблицей. Для полной картины выкладываю код с созданием таблицы.

```py
import sqlite3


conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
c = conn.cursor()

# Создание таблицы Article с полями articleid (целое число заполняется автоматически, уникально) и title (текст)
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Article(
   articleid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   title TEXT);
""")
conn.commit()

title = [['Вова'], ['Дима'], ['Илья']]

c.executemany("INSERT INTO Article(title) VALUES (?)",  (title))

conn.commit()

# Попробуем вывести содержимое БД
res = c.execute("SELECT * FROM Article")
print(res.fetchall())
# [(1, 'Вова'), (2, 'Дима'), (3, 'Илья')]
conn.close()
```

Более подробно о работе с sqlite можно почитать [здесь](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-sqlite3-python/)